# Esta consulta me funciona bien en mysql pero quiero pasarlo a la forma CodeIgniter , models

Tags: codeigniter

Esta consulta me funciona bien en mysql pero quiero pasarlo a la forma CodeIgniter , models, me pueden ayudar con esto:

```
SELECT registro.*,CONCAT(usuarios.apellidos,', ',usuarios.nombres) as appnom FROM (SELECT *, bingo+chancho+pollada as total FROM (SELECT idusuario, sum(pagado) as bingo, sum('') as chancho, sum('') as pollada, 1 as tarjeta FROM tbingo b WHERE pagado=1 GROUP BY idusuario
union all
SELECT idusuario,  sum('') as bingo, sum(pagado) as chancho, sum('') as pollada, 2 as tarjeta FROM tchancho c WHERE pagado=1 GROUP BY idusuario
union all
SELECT idusuario,  sum('') as bingo, sum('') as chancho, sum(pagado) as pollada, 3 as tarjeta FROM tpollada  p WHERE pagado=1  GROUP BY idusuario) as tabla  
GROUP BY idusuario) as registro join usuarios  ON registro.idusuario=usuarios.id
```

Answer (score 1):

ya encontré la respuesta tanto buscar y buscar ...

```
class Cobradores_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getCobradores(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT registro.*,CONCAT(usuarios.apellidos,', ',usuarios.nombres) as appnom FROM (SELECT *, bingo+chancho+pollada as total FROM (SELECT idusuario, sum(pagado) as bingo, sum('') as chancho, sum('') as pollada, 1 as tarjeta FROM tbingo b WHERE pagado=1 GROUP BY idusuario
        union all
        SELECT idusuario,  sum('') as bingo, sum(pagado) as chancho, sum('') as pollada, 2 as tarjeta FROM tchancho c WHERE pagado=1 GROUP BY idusuario
        union all
        SELECT idusuario,  sum('') as bingo, sum('') as chancho, sum(pagado) as pollada, 3 as tarjeta FROM tpollada  p WHERE pagado=1  GROUP BY idusuario) as tabla  
        GROUP BY idusuario) as registro join usuarios  ON registro.idusuario=usuarios.id");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```